# Solution of Recurrence Relation for 1/2-integers

Tags: recurrence-relations, analyticity

Suppose one wants to solve a recurrence relation of the form

$$
c(m+1) - c(m)/f(m) = -g(m)
$$
for $c(m)$. The general solution can be given by
$$
c(m) = \left(\prod_{\mu=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{f(\mu)}\right)\left(c_0 - \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}g(k)\prod_{\nu=0}^{k}f(\nu)\right)
$$

However, this doesn't, at least in this form, immediately work when I try to extend the solution to half-integer arguments. I also need to modify it to work with negative arguments. Is there a general process that one can follow to analytically continue the solutions to a recurrence to half-integer arguments? Perhaps rephrase the original recurrence? Or is there no good way to do this?

I would also accept willingly as an answer conditions for when it is or is not possible to do this, or even a vague outline of such conditions.

Comment: do you know anything about $f(m)$ and $g(m)$?

Comment: Sure. In my particular problem, f(m) = $\sqrt{j(j+1)-m(m+1)}$, and $g(m)$ is a product of $f(m)$ for various m.

Comment: You could write your recurrence in terms of half steps, i.e., $d(2 m + 2) - d(2 m) / f(m) = - g(m)$ and see where that leads you. Sadly, there probably isn't any closed(ish) solution for this second order recurrence.

Comment: @vonbrand That's what I had kind of imagined. I wouldn't know how to solve recurrences like that except in really special cases (for example, constant coefficients I would know how to do analytically). I suppose my "bandage" fix for now might have to be to add a term $\cos^2(\pi m)$, so that the half-integer arguments trivially solve the recurrence.

Comment: On second thought, I guess it would technically be possible to try and apply semi-group theory to such an equation and convert it into a differential equation.